# Permission denied when trying to execute C code?

Tags: c, permissions, putty

line.c is my main program and it checks for a certain condition in any given input file and writes the answer to a new file.
I'm trying to run the following in PuTTY:

```
line.c <linetest.txt >lineouttput
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
-bash: ./line.c Permission denied
```

It does create a file name lineoutput but it's empty.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 4):

A text file containing C code is not an executable. You'll need to use a compiler and linker to create an executable.

```
gcc -o line line.c
```

and then

```
./line < linetest.txt >lineouttput
```

should work.

Answer (score -1):

chmod 755 on the file it's probably doesn't have execute permissions.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick provided you are allowed to use chmod.

```
chmod +x line.c
```